# Checkboxes in ListView mixed when scrolling the list

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I'm trying to set a ListView that each row contains CheckBox, TextView and ImageView.
I use my own adapter in the implementation, but when I'm scrolling down some Checkbox is checked without no reason:
For example, I check checkbox in the first row (in the 0 position), scrolling down and suddenly the element in row 17 is also checked, and sometime if I turned back to the first the checkbox is not checked.

I used the following code:

```
private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView name;
        CheckBox selected;
    }

private class BrowserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public BrowserAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browser_list_row, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.browser_image);

            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.browser_file_name);
            holder.name.setOnClickListener(ActionBar.this);

            holder.selected = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.browser_selected);
            holder.selected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(ActionBar.this);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();             

        }

        setViewInfo(holder.image, holder.name, holder.selected, position);

        return convertView;
    }

    private void setViewInfo(ImageView image, TextView name, CheckBox selected , int position) {

        name.setTag(position);

        selected.setTag(position);
        selected.setChecked(checkedItems[position]);

        name.setText(myList.get(position));
        File temp_file = new File( file, myList.get( position ) );

        if (temp_file.isFile())
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mp3file);
        else
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.folder);
    }

}//class BroswerAdapter
```

The argument checkedItems is a boolean array that save the state of the checkboxes in the list like in the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    checkedItems[(Integer)buttonView.getTag()] = isChecked;

}
```

Can you please help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: when I use the naive way of inflating a view every time the getView function is called (without using the convertView) everything works good.

Answer (score 0):

move the following lines outside the if statement

```
 holder.name.setOnClickListener(ActionBar.this);
 holder.selected = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.browser_selected);
 holder.selected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(ActionBar.this);
```

Answer (score -1):

**WRONG:**

> You are using `setSelected`, while you should be using [setChecked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29)
>   on the `CheckBox` View like this:
>
> ```
> selected.setChecked (checkedItems[position]);
> ```
>
> The setSelected method sets the selection state of a *row* within a
>   `ListView` (or another `AdapterView`).

**EDIT:**

You set the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to the `CheckBox` view. Then, you try to read the tag of the view that the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` was set to -- this is the `CheckBox`. However, you never set the tag of the `CheckBox`! So, the tag you read in the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` is wrong.

You have to set it like this:

```
holder.selected.setTag ("" + position);
```

... and then, in the `setOnCheckedChangeListener`, read it like this:

```
checkedItems[Integer.parseInt (buttonView.getTag())] = isChecked;
```

Comment: I also tried to change it to setChecked() method but checkboxed still mixed and the problem still happens.

Comment: Under the private function SetViewInfo(), I set the tag of the checkbox to be the position. I also tried to log the number of each checkbox that I select and it prints the correct number of each checkbox.